CdpVersionFinder incorrectly detects the chromium-based browser version
I'm trying to write code (Java, Selenium) for connect to DevTools.
At devTools.createSession() line, I see error:
org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevToolsException: You are using a no-op implementation of the CDP. The most likely reason for this is that Selenium was unable to find an implementation of the CDP protocol that matches your browser. Please be sure to include an implementation on the classpath, possibly by adding a new (maven) dependency of `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-vNN:4.14.0` where `NN` matches the major version of the browser you're using.
Build info: version: '4.14.0', revision: 'e5a96349ce'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '22'
Driver info: DevTools Connection

In topic of run console, I see warning:
апр. 04, 2024 1:07:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 9
апр. 04, 2024 1:07:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$5
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for 9.2.63.1. You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.14.0` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.

I know that chrome with version 9.2.63.1 doesn't exist, but my custom browser version is 9.2.63.1.
In "about browser" window I can see this:

Version: 9.2.63.1 Core: 116.0.5845.110

I understand that "core" is version of chrome, but CdpVersionFinder take incorrect version.
I found a lot of solutions and try all of them, but it's not helpful me.

import dependency selenium-devtools-vVERSION:4.14.0
import other selenium version
change browser version by chromeOptions (impossible)... etc

I can't install new version of browser and unfortunately can't past a lot of code there.

I think even if you are able to hack selenium's CDP version detection or change your capabilities for (browser: chrome/v116...)  it probably wouldn't work.  The CDP protocol is supported by specific browsers... (I think currently it's Chrome, Edge and Firefox?)  It's outside of Chromium... what browser is this?

My browser driven by custom chrome driver and it works good in generally. It is custom browser for my company. I found solving and answer for my question.

I successfully solved the problem. I overridden the class that switch cdp version for chrome driver. In new class I write version of browser that I need and it works good.
Documentation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-in-java/amp/

Might want to add your code so you can help others who might have the same problem.

Yes, I can add my code later
